# :!make is at least 10times slower compared to terminal on MacOS X

Tags: gvim, macvim, macos

I am using MacVim version 7.4.
I am authoring a large LaTeX file and I use a GNU Makefile to compile the documents along with lots of figures and other targets. The command `make` generates lots of output text from executing `pdflatex` several times.

**My problem:** When I use `:!make` from `gvim` it works correctly, however, it is at least 10 times slower than typing `make` in a terminal. I tried the same experiments from `vim` in a terminal, and it seems to work fine.
Is there a fix to get `gvim` up to speed?

Comment: And what about `:make` (there are no reasons nowadays to use `:!make`)?

Comment: @Nobe4 : can you clarify a bit where/how do I use silent?

Comment: @LucHermitte: `:make` in vim-latex-suite executes `pdflatex` in its own way. I have lots of other targets for different graphics and bibliography in my own GNU Makefile. This is why I need to run the actual make. If there is a way to get it working with just `:make` please let me know.

Comment: @Bichoy You can unset `makeprg` to get `:make` to run `make` again.